# Not expected output in bit-masking an integer in Python

Tags: python

The following data is added to a bitstream

```
bitstream.add(BYTE_OFFSET_SIZE_FLAG, 1)  # value = 0
bitstream.add(NON_OVERLAPPING_AU_RANGE_FLAG, 1)  # value = 0
bitstream.add(POS_40_BITS_FLAG, 1)  # value = 0
bitstream.add(BLOCK_HEADER_FLAG, 1)  # value = 1
bitstream.add(MIT_FLAG, 1)  # value = 1
bitstream.add(CC_MODE_FLAG, 1) # # value = 1
bitstream.add(0, 2)  # to make the bitstream of 8 bits
```

When I unpack it:

```
data = struct.unpack('>B', in_file.read(1))[0] # evaluates to 28, in bin 00011100
ds_header["byte_offset_size_flag"] = data >> 7 # value = 0
ds_header["non_overlapping_au_range_flag"] = data >> 6 & 0x01  # value = 0
ds_header["pos_40_bits_flag"] = data >> 5 & 0x001 # value = 0
ds_header["block_header_flag"] = data >> 4 & 0x0001 # value = 1
ds_header["mit_flag"] = data >> 3 & 0x00001  # value = 1
ds_header["cc_mode_flag"] = data >> 2 & 0x000001 # value = 1

ignore = data & 0x00000011 # value = 16, but 0 is expected
```

I do not really understand why the `ignore` value is 16, since the last 2 bits of data are 00..
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you mean 0b00000011 instead of 0x00000011? It didn't matter above because it's only one bit

Comment: `0x00000011` is 17 and `28 & 17 = 16` is correct. I suspect that you want `b` everywhere that you have `x` in the above code (although as @Marat points out, you got lucky in the other places).

Comment: no, I meant 0x00000011.. With your mask it does work. Why do the other masks work? Sorry, but I'm totally a newby in bit manipulation operations.

Comment: `0x00000011` is in base 16, not base 2. Hex isn't binary (though they are naturally related). The meaning of `0x00000011` is 1x16 + 1 = 17, not `1x2 +1 = 3`

Comment: @JohnColeman: ahh okay, now I see also why the other masks are working.. thank you

Comment: if you make it an answer, I flag the question as resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0x00000011` is 17 and `28 & 17 = 16` is correct. As @Marat observed, you probably intended `0b00000011`. The `x` flags the literal as base 16, and 1+16 = 17. The `b` would flag it as its intended base 2. Since the value of `01` is 1 in all bases, the error didn't bite you earlier in the computation, but even there the `x` should probably be changed to `b` for clarity.